# Angular 2 - use cshtml instead of html in Asp.Net mvc 4x

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, web-config, angular2-routing

I've created asp.net mvc application using angular 2 following this [template](https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015)

**My app:**

***index.cshtml***

```
@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="@Url.Content("~/")">
    <title>MVC 4 Angular 4</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="dist/scripts/packages/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/scripts/packages/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/scripts/packages/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('dist/scripts/main.js').catch(function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

***main.ts***

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

***app.module.ts***

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

import { AppComponent } from "./Components/app";
import { Page1 } from "./Components/page1";
import { Page2 } from "./Components/page2";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: 'page1',
                component: Page1
            },
            {
                path: 'page2',
                component: Page2
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/page1',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ])
        // other imports here
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        Page1,
        Page2
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***app.ts***

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
            <h1>{{app}}</h1>
            <nav id="main-menu">
                 <a class="menu-item" routerLink="/page1" routerLinkActive="active">Page1</a>
                <a class="menu-item" routerLink="/page2" routerLinkActive="active">Page2</a>
            </nav>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            `
})
export class AppComponent {
    app= "App"
}
```

***page1.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'page1',
    template: "<div>page1</div>",
    styleUrls: []
})
export class Page1 { }
```

So in order angular 2 to work on asp.net mvc project, according to the documentation, the `web.config` should contains this code:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/src/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

So, after this, it works just fine when I use static html, or inline html into the component.

[image]

What I want is to use cshtml instead of html, so my component will look like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'page1',
    templateUrl: "home/about",
    styleUrls: []
})
export class Page1 { }
```

***home/about*** is in my home controller:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
  ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
  return View();
}
```

But then, I get this:

[image]

If I remove the `<system.webServer>` from the `web.config` **it works just fine** except when I refresh the page (press f5), then I get this:

[image]

At the very end of the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015) you can see this paragraph:

> The match url, , will rewrite every request. You'll
>   have to adjust this if you want some requests to get through, such as
>   web API requests.

So my question is how to configure the `web.config`, or something else to avoid this issue ?

Comment: I guess your server doesn't support or is not configured to support HTML5 pushState. Try `RouterModule.forRoot([...], {useHash: true})`. If it works this way that this would confirm my suspicion.

Comment: it works :) i also removed the `<system.webServer>` tag. Thank you very much.